# Tabbed Coded Windows With Dreamweaver Layout?

Tags: dreamweaver

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to manage more than one website in Dreamweaver at the same time? As I understand it now, every time I need to get a page from a website, I have to change the current site by selecting another site in the Files dropdown... Is there a way to have something like "tabs" where you can instantly switch between different websites without having to click the Files drop-down, select the website, wait for FTP to connect, and then browse that website?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 and when I open multiple webpages, they are on tabs already. On the fist screen shot i provided, you can see that index.html and album.html are both opened. If you click on the restore button on the active window (icon encircled), it is manageable like the other image I attached.

[image]

[image]